# returned json data from table always repeats the one before last

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a div which uses long polling to update with table data, it all works except when I enter a new piece of text, the text that was inserted before that **always appears first** and **then** what I just wrote.

so, if I write hi, hello, goodbye I will get the following:

```
hi
hi
hello
hello
goodbye
```

relevant JS:

```
var timestamp = null;
function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'update.php?timestamp=' + timestamp,
        async: true,
        cache: false,

        success:function(data) {
            // alert(data);
            var json = eval('('+data+')');
            if (json['msg']) {
                $('.chat_contacts .inner_chat').append(json['msg']+'<br>'); // MD
            }
            timestamp = json['timestamp'];
            setTimeout('waitForMsg()', 1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // alert('error '+textStatus+'('+errorThrown+')');
            setTimeout('waitForMsg()', 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

relevant snippet from update.php

```
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $nou = $row['f1'];
    $nru = $row['f2'];
    $response['msg'] = $row['content'];
    $response['timestamp'] = $row['time'];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Why doesn't it just detect the last thing entered and display that alone, without repeating the previous data that was entered?

EDIT:
I noticed something.

It also appears to be swallowing what is entered, so if the table is empty, and i write "hi", I get hi, but then if I write "hello", i get "hi" again, and THEN if I write something else I get "hello" (and not what I just wrote) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$response['msg'] = $row['content'];` with `$response['msg'][] = $row['content'];`

And change below `JS` code

```
if (json['msg']) { 
    $('.chat_contacts .inner_chat').append(json['msg'] + '<br>');
} // MD
```

With

```
if (json['msg'].length) { 
    var el = $('.chat_contacts .inner_chat');
    $.each(json['msg'], function(i, v) { 
        el.append(v + '<br>'); //MD 
    }); 
}
```

And make sure in `sql query` you are using something like this `WHERE time > timestamp`

Comment: No good, acting the same plus it returns everything from the table, not just last insert.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same. I updated my question, I broke down the situation a bit more.